# Using a React Native FlatList with two completely different arrays of data

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have two arrays, one for products, and one for supervisors. Obviously, both have very different types of data. I want to create a scrollable list that will display all of the products followed by all of the supervisors using a single scrolling list. Is this possible with React Native's FlatList? If so, or if not, how can I go about doing this?

I can currently render a single data array as follows:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.products}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
/>
```

But, how can I append the supervisors data to the end of this list? Obviously, because the data is quite different between the two arrays I cannot simply merge the arrays and or the same renderItem function.

How can I display two completely different types of data one after the other in the same scrollable list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can merge your data together and use single FlatList with a single renderItem prop. Without a sample of your data its a little guessing game but below is an example how you can do.

**Example**

Let's assume you have data structure like below.

```
const Products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Product 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Product 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Product 3'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Product 4'
  },
];

const Supervisors = [
  {
    belongsToPruduct: 1,
    name: 'SuperVisor 1' 
  },
  {
    belongsToPruduct: 3,
    name: 'SuperVisor 2' 
  },
  {
    belongsToPruduct: 2,
    name: 'SuperVisor 3' 
  },
  {
    belongsToPruduct: 4,
    name: 'SuperVisor 4' 
  }
];
```

And let's assume you render `Products` in a `FlatList`. You can do something like below in your `renderItem` function

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  const superviors = Supervisors.filter((supervisor) => supervisor.belongsToPruduct === item.id)
  return (
    <View style={styles.productContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.productName}>{item.name}</Text>
        <View style={styles.supervisorsContainer}>
          {
            superviors.map((supervisor) => <Text style={styles.supervisorName}>{supervisor.name}</Text>)
          }
        </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

**UPDATE**

Referring to your comment I think then you can get use of [`SectionList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) rather than `FlatList`

```
<SectionList 
   renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{title}</Text>} 
   sections={[ 
     { title: 'Products', data: Products, renderItem: ({ item, index, section: { title, data } }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text> }, 
     { title: 'Supervisors', data: Supervisors, renderItem: ({ item, index, section: { title, data } }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}, 
    ]} 
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name + index} 
 />
```

Comment: The supervisors don't belong to specific products. In a way, they are completely separate entities. So basically I want a single scrollable list. The upper part of the list will contain products and the lower part of the list will contain supervisors. So once you scroll to the end of the products it will show you the supervisors in the same scroll motion. I do want there to be a heading of "Products" and "Supervisors" at the top of each section.

Answer (score 1):

I did this by creating a third array which contains `FlatList` compononets. Then rendered only the third array with new `FlatList` component